# How to merge various ranges from multiple sheets into one single variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a worksheet with multiple sheets and I want to apply some formatting such as background color modification, setting borders, etc.

If I store all the ranges from all the sheets into multiple variables, the script becomes floated with many variables.

So, what I want to do is for the all cells and/or ranges from multiple sheets, I want to declare one single variable for background, for border setting, for font style.

I have seen a code but it only merges all ranges within the same sheet, which can be also done with getRangeList.

I have tried the following;

```
var colors = ss.getRangeByName("colorPalette").getValues();
var bigBox = [s2.getRangeList(['a1:c4','f4:j9']) + s3.getRange('b3:g9')];
var smlBox = ss.getRangeByName("smlBox");
var theme = sheet.getRange(19,1,1,1).getValue();


Logger.log(colors[theme-1][2]);

for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
bigBox.setBackground(colors[theme-1][2]);
smlBox.setBackground(colors[theme-1][1]);
}
```

But when I run the script, it throws an error saying that bigBox.setBackground is not a function.

Could you please tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!,

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I don't think you can get border settings in a 2d array.

Comment: Well they save the entire contents of our script projects in one JSON file that we often assign to one variable when we extract it from the Apps Script API.

Comment: @Cooper, well I rewrote the code with forEach and it worked well.  When you say 2d array, if I am not mistaken, you are talking about a matrix consisting of multiple rows and columns, yes, I could change the border style and color with the script.  In fact, I decided to use the script as conditional formatting does not allow us to modify the border settings, unfortunately.  Although this works slow, there is no solution I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator adds numbers and concatenates text strings. It cannot be used to combine arrays or ranges. Use `Array.forEach()`, like this:

```js
  const theme = sheet.getRange('S1').getValue();
  const colors = ss.getRange('colorPalette').getValues();
  const bigBox = [
    s2.getRangeList(['A1:C4', 'F4:J9']),
    s3.getRangeList(['B3:G9']),
  ];
  bigBox.forEach(rangeList => {
    rangeList.setBackground(colors[theme - 1][2]);
  });
  const smlBox = ss.getRange('smlBox');
  smlBox.setBackground(colors[theme - 1][1]);
```

See [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works like a charm! So, if I do not misunderstand, for each variable, I need to repeat this forEach, right? I mean let's assume that I have some other variables such as bigBoxBackground, bigBoxBorder, smlBoxBackground, etc. In this case,  I need to write forEach as many as the number of variables, right ?

Comment: To apply additional operations to all the rangeLists in `bigBox`, put those operations inside the one and only `forEach()`. See [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) for available operations. To learn more, see [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).